# API Google Maps Javascript calling event listener inside context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API V3, and a context menu that I created. I want to get the coords of the position of the mouse on the map whenever I click the menu inside the context menu. Except I have no idea on how to do that.

This is what I tried to do:

```
contextmenuDir.innerHTML = "<a id='menu1' onclick='google.maps.event.addListener(menu1, 'click', function(event) {
      var lat = event.latLng.lat();
      var lng = event.latLng.lng();
      changeBeginCoords(lat,lng);
    });'><div class=context>Direccoes a partir daqui<\/div><\/a>";
```

Anybody know how I can do this?

EDIT.: Okay, I managed to advance a bit further, and now I can enter the event listener whenever I press the menu of the context menu.

```
var m1 = document.getElementById("menu1");
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(m1, "click", function(event) {
      var lat = event.latLng.lat();
      var lng = event.latLng.lng();
      changeBeginCoords(lat,lng);
      // populate yor box/field with lat, lng
    });
```

Now a way to figure out this error:
`Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some digging, I found the method addDomListener.
Here is how my code ended up being:

```
var m1 = document.getElementById("menu1");
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(m1, "click", function(event) {
      var lat = lati;
      var lng = lngi;
      changeBeginCoords(lat,lng);
      hideContextMenu();
      // populate yor box/field with lat, lng
    });
```

`lati` and `lngi` are the new coordinates. I retrieve them when I rightclick on the map to see the context menu.